# Выпадающие меню на Wordpress

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

Как сделать из стандартного меню Wordpress мультиуровневое выпадающее меню с иконкой (стрелка вниз и вверх когда открываешь меню)

Answer (score 2):

Либо вы используете стандартный вывод меню и стилизуете используя стандартные классы (там их предостаточно, чтобы сделать любое меню).

Либо можете написать свой Walker тут есть пример реализации: https://wp-kama.ru/function/wp_nav_menu

Answer (score 0):

> Как сделать из стандартного меню Wordpress мультиуровневое выпадающее
>   меню

Просто мышей сдвинуть пункты.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Иконки - css.